# Get a string of values and their count using LINQ

Tags: string, vb.net, linq

I have a list of accounts delimited by pipe, I need to return a list with how many times this account appears in the list. The new list must have same number of indexes as the original list.

Example:

`INPUT: 111|111|222|333|333|111|333|444|555|555|111`

`OUTPUT: 4|4|1|3|3|4|3|1|2|2|4`

So far I could manage only to retrieve a sum of accounts, but it groups them together:

```
string.Join("|",  str.Split("|").GroupBy(Function(x) x).[Select](Function(y) y.Count()).ToList())
```

`INPUT: 111|111|222|333|333|111|333|444|555|555|111`

`OUTPUT: 4|1|3|1|2`

Thank you for any help

**EDIT 1:** Apologies, looks like I messed up with the INPUT/OUTPUT example not correlating to the requirements. I also forgot to mention another requirement - the sequence of output elements must be the same as the original (see updated INPUT/OUTPUT example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the input string using the known separator, group by the split values, the `Join()` back each part with the separator using the strings on each Grouping as the iterator of the final `Select()` part, where the string values of the Grouping are not actually considered, while the `Group.Count()` is:

```
Dim input = "111|111|222|333|333|333|444|555|555"
Dim output = String.Join("|"c, acc.Split("|"c).GroupBy(Function(s) s).
    Select(Function(grp) String.Join("|", grp.Select(Function(nan) grp.Count()))))
```

`output` is `2|2|1|3|3|3|1|2|2` here.

There's an `Aggregate()` variant, in case it's more interesting: you can aggregate the resulting `Grouping.Count()` using a StringBuilder and `Concat()` the final `IEnumerable<StringBuilder>`:

```
Dim output = String.Concat(input.Split("|"c).GroupBy(Function(s) s).Select(Function(g) 
    g.Aggregate(New StringBuilder(), Function(sb, s) sb.AppendFormat("{0}|", g.Count()))))
```

Since it's actually a *segmented* - no sequential - input, a simple way is to turn the Grouping into a Dictionary and use the the sequential elements of the split input string as the Key:

```
Dim splitInput = input.Split("|"c)
Dim groups = splitInput.GroupBy(Function(s) s).ToDictionary(Function(g) g.Key, Function(g) g.Count)

' Aggregate using a StringBuilder
Dim output = splitInput.Aggregate(
    New StringBuilder, Function(sb, s) sb.AppendFormat("{0}|", groups(s))).ToString()

' Or Join values as strings
Dim output = String.Join("|"c, splitInput.Select(Function(s) groups(s)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. I forgot to mention another requirement, the sequence of output elements must be the same as the input elements. I updated my question. For input `111|111|222|333|333|111|333|444|555|555|111` both of your code samples produce `4|4|4|4|1|3|3|3|1|2|2|` but should be producing `4|4|1|3|3|4|3|1|2|2|4`. It should not be grouping the totals like it did the `4` for `111`

Comment: See the edit, maybe it's good enough for what you need.

Comment: The new code works perfectly, both aggregate and join. I was working on similar code you have, up until getting a dictionary with totals, but then I had a For Each loop going against each element and looking for key in the dictionary and appending a total. I was hoping to get a LINQ version of that code, but my limited knowledge of LINQ made me struggle. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Dictionary` to map the account #s to their counts:

```
Dim accountCountMap = str.Split("|").GroupBy(Function(s) s) _
                                    .Select(Function(sg) (sg.Key, sg.Count())) _
                                    .ToDictionary(Function(kc) kc.Key, Function(kc) kc.Count)
```

Then use the `Dictionary` to map the accounts to their accounts:

```
Dim ans = String.Join("|", str.Split("|").Select(Function(s) accountCountMap(s)))
```

Comment: I get this error when using your code `Error BC37289 Tuple element name 'Key' is inferred. Please use language version 15.3 or greater to access an element by its inferred name.`